# show and change parameter threadpool.bulk.queue_size

Tags: elasticsearch, threadpool

I am using an elasticsearch version 6.7.2 and I have error 429

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "remote_transport_exception",
                "reason": "[localhost][localhost:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s]]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "es_rejected_execution_exception",
        "reason": "rejected execution of processing of [682604930][indices:data/write/bulk[s][p]]: request: BulkShardRequest [[hboauth2-2020.04.20-000113][0]] containing [index {[hboauth2][_doc][yRuEnHEBn6z33bhuCGjZ], source[{\"Action\":\"Service UpdateUserStatus Start\",\"ClientID\":\"\",\"Code\":0,\"Component\":\"UpdateUserStatus\",\"CustomMessage\":\"\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"LogDate\":1587468830939,\"Message\":\"{OK false}\",\"Type\":\"Info\",\"UserID\":\"4c220ab2-282d-466f-a9f5-da0e59b7b803\"}]}], target allocation id: wZFZUPi5TnSYFg-BNonHug, primary term: 1 on EsThreadPoolExecutor[name = localhost/write, queue capacity = 200, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@744831b0[Running, pool size = 16, active threads = 16, queued tasks = 224, completed tasks = 264136589]]"
    },
    "status": 429
}
```

I found a solution to the problem, but I can not find the parameter threadpool.bulk.queue_size in my version.
could you please help me how to find and change this parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As shown in the [official example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html), you can change the queue size of bulk thread pool using the below config in your elasticsearch.config or update the cluster setting.**

Note, write thread pool is used for bulk request as documented in the same link:

> write For single-document index/delete/update and **bulk requests**.
>   Thread pool type is fixed with a size of # of available processors,
>   queue_size of 200. The maximum size for this pool is 1 + # of
>   available processors.

```
thread_pool:
    write:
        size: 30. --> no if threads in your case, its 16 as shown in exception
        queue_size: 400 --> here you can add `queue_size`
```

**Instruction on changing these settings also mentioned**

> Changing a specific thread pool can be done by setting its
>   type-specific parameters; for example, changing the number of threads
>   in the write thread pool:

Edit: **As pointed out by @val in the comment section, Adding disclaimer about changing these default settings.**

Please understand the technicalities of these settings and the impact, as these are often not advisable to change, more info in [this official blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/why-am-i-seeing-bulk-rejections-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster)

Comment: You're missing the instructions on how to change the number of threads

Comment: Also be [aware of this official advice](https://www.elastic.co/blog/why-am-i-seeing-bulk-rejections-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster): Adjusting the queue sizes is therefore strongly discouraged, as it is like putting a temporary band-aid on the problem rather than actually fixing the underlying issue.

Comment: @Val, for your first comment, Please see begining of my answer, I mentioned that it can be changed in `elasticsearch.config` and reg the warning, I thought of doing so, but OP mentioned  he found a solution and asked how to change it, so I thought, he read about these disclaimer as they come in google result at top, when searching for these exceptions:), but thanks for your advise, i would add this for future readers :)

Comment: I was probably confused with the colon at the very end, which means "something is coming next"

Comment: @Val, modified it added ur suggestion. please check and let me know if it looks fine :)

Answer (score 1):

i was searching how i can change thread_pool.write.queue_size and find 2 solutions
first

```
curl -XPUT  _cluster/settings -d '{
    "persistent" : {
        "thread_pool.write.queue_size" : <new_size>
    }
}'
```

second write to elasticsearch.yaml paramater thread_pool.write.queue_size

all solutions are valid for my version 6.2.7?

Comment: Yes, both are valid and I mentioned them in my answer with explanation, I didn't understand why you posted this answer as the same information is covered in the first line of my answer. Let me know if you were able to change it, happy to help further :)

Comment: Hi did you get a chance to look at my comment?

Comment: i write parameter in elasticsearch.yaml and  changed  successufully. I wanted to be sure that I configured correctly:)